# What is the policy on creating new tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have noticed that there are quite a few one question tags, which I think are superfluous: [peroxide](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/peroxide)  [anaesthetics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anaesthetics) [dessicant](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dessicant) (which is also spelled wrong) [uppsalite](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uppsalite) (also wrong) [paraquat](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paraquat) and there might be many more.

I believe it is best to review some of them put them up for discussion and remove them or at least give them a meaningful wiki (short description to start with). For all of the above I am for immediate striking.

Comment: I would probably remove most and retag with the more general tags. I removed uppsalite and paraquat from their questions, they ought to disappear in a day.

Comment: Perhaps someone could create a reference-type answer here... @DEAD